# Condition for axially symmetric ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, symmetry, ellipsoids

Can someone help me understand what the condition is for an ellipsoid to be considered axially symmetric?

If I have an ellipsoid with a = 8.00e-07, then what should the values of the parameters b and c be such that I have an axially symmetric ellipsoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take the usual convention

$$a \ge b \ge c,$$

you can have an axially symmetric ellipsoid in one of the following two forms:

- either $a \ = b \ge c $ (**oblate** form),
- or $a \ge b \ = \ c$, (**prolate** form).

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheroid#:%7E:text=oblate,A%20spheroid%20has%20circular%20symmetry).

With of course the particular case $a = b = c$ for the sphere.

Comment: okay! thank you.